# lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ubuntu

So I stupidly ran a "dkpg -i" command which had a load of dependencies which probably overwrite a lot of modules even up to the libc level.

All command I run now gives me as shown below:

lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (require by...)

Eg: ls, mv, apt-get update...

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have libc6 package installed. It seems, your libc6 package got downgraded. If apt-get gives you error, try downloading the latest from [ubuntu repo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc6&searchon=names) . Install both libc6 and libc6-dev of higher like 2.19.. Hopefully this will resolve your issue